# Getting 400 Bad request when building JSON Object to send with POST

Tags: jquery, json, rest

I am trying to build a JSON to send with a POST, but it seems that I am doing something wrong:

```
var encodedRdf = base64_encode(rdf);
var data = '{"path": path, "rdf": encodedRdf}';
```

This way I get 400 Bad Request error and it does't fire the REST at all.

Instead if I put hard coded strings as follows it works fine:

```
var encodedRdf = base64_encode(rdf);
var data = '{"path": "ppp", "rdf": "rrr"}';
```

Any ideas?

Thanks,

Comment: It's probably dues to the fact that encodedRdf doesn't get added to the data string. Try: `'{"path": ' + path + ', "rdf": ' + encodedRdf + '}';`

Comment: @GerardWesterhof same thing.

Comment: Creating the JSON object, setting the fields and JSON.stringify solved it!

Answer (score 1):

Your var data = '{"path": path, "rdf": encodedRdf}'; is not valid, the variables path and encodedRdf are not calculated and are passed like 'path' and 'encodedRdf'. Try passing like:

```
var data = {
    path: path,
    rdf: encodedRdf
}
```

Comment: Creating the JSON object, setting the fields and JSON.stringify solved it!

Answer (score 0):

This solved it.

```
   data: JSON.stringify(data),
```